# Is $\{a^ib^ja^k \mid j \text{ is odd, then } k=i^2+j ;\ j \text{ is even, then } k =i+j\}$ context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

$L=\{a^ib^ja^k \mid j \text{ is odd, then } k=i^2+j
;\ j \text{ is even, then } k =i+j\}$

I tried writing $L$ as the union of the language created with $j$ odd and the one with $j$ even.

When $j$ is odd, I can prove using the pumping lemma that it is not a cfl.

When $j$ is even, I can prove that it is a cfl by writing a context-free grammar for it.

But then the union of a cfl and a non-cfl doesn't really help me prove $L$ is a cfl or not.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Try to show that $a^ib^{i^2}$ is not context free. That might help.

Comment: @NarekBojikian I can do that, but I don't really see how this will help me. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Pete42 Have you tried proving $L$ is not cfl using pumping lemma?

Comment: @JohnL. Well, I was not sure it would yield the correct solution. But since you mentioned it, is it correct to choose $j=2p + 1$, where $p$ is the constant from the pumping lemma, so that I get a string from the odd case. I can prove this is not CFL and it is contained in L, so this proves L is not CFL ? It seems to ignore the case where $j$ is even, but according to the statement of the pumping lemma it seems correct. Is this solution right ?

Comment: @Pete42 Can you post your solution as an answer? I could edit your answer in case it is not correct or upvote it otherwise. (Other users can do that, too, of course).

Comment: @JohnL. I posted my solution. It's not really formal, but intuitively it seems to work.

Comment: The union of disjoint grammars is easier to reason about than general union.

Comment: @Pete42 We can also use closure property. For example, $L\cap b(b^2)^*a^* = \{b^ja^{j^2}\mid j\text{ is odd}\}$, where $b(b^2)^*a^*$ is regular while the right-hand side is not context-free.

Comment: @JohnL. Didn't think of that. It's way easier this way. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

We can prove $L$ is not a CFL using the pumping lemma by choosing the string $a^pb^{1}a^{p^2+1}$, where $p$ is the constant in the pumping lemma.

Since $|vwx|\le{p}$, we can have:

If $v$ or $x$ contains more than one type of letter, so when we pump the order breaks.

If both $v$ and $x$ contain only $a$'s then when we pump the sum breaks because we either don't add enough letters or we add too much(the case with $i^2$ when pumping the first $a$'s).

The only other case is when either $v=b$ or $x=b$ that we solve by pumping $v$ down to 0, so the new string will match the $j$ even case with $j=0$, but $i + j = p^2$ while $k = p^2 + 1$.

Comment: @JohnL. I updated. Is it ok?

Comment: $v=b$, $w=\epsilon$, $x=a^{p^2+1-p}$. Pumping $v$ down to $\epsilon$, we get $a^pa^p\in L$.

Comment: Yea, you're right. The pumping lemma solution isn't that easy after all or I didn't pick the right string at least.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the context-free languages are closed under [left-quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_of_a_formal_language) as well as intersection with regular languages, as John L. noted.

Assume, for contradiction, that $L$ was context-free.
Then
$$L_1 := L \cap a^*ba^* = \{a^iba^{i^2 + 1} : i \geq 0\}$$
and
$$L_2 :=  a^*ba \setminus L_1 = \{a^{i^2} : i \geq 0\}$$
must be context-free as well.
If $L_2$ is context-free then it must also be regular, [since it only contains one letter](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40791/proving-that-any-cf-language-over-a-1-letter-alphabet-is-regular).

But using the Pumping lemma for regular languages it can be shown that $L_2$ [isn't regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3075/proof-that-an2-is-not-regular), contradicting our assumption that $L$ is context-free ↯